# tried ntfs format in terminal but says internal error

Tags: usb, format

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 with Linux kernel 3.8 which has ntfs-3g package but again asks to install it, when tried the terminal does not respond!
as I am new to ask Ubuntu I'm not allowed to post the links else I would do it.
http://tripleasolutions.freeiz.com/456.png

Comment: Please paste the exact output in question.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do. Are you trying to format the partition where Ubuntu is installed? Are you trying to format an external hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

---

1st of all its a bug [mkfs.ntfs link is broken and fails](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1148541)

Just copy paste the following command to **FIX** it.

```
sudo ln -s /sbin/mkntfs  /usr/sbin/mkntfs
```

## OR

```
sudo rm -rf /sbin/mkfs.ntfs && sudo ln -s /sbin/mkntfs /sbin/mkfs.ntfs
```

### Done

```
sudo mkfs.
```

[image]

---

If you do

```
locate mkfs.ntfs
```

The output will be

```
/sbin/mkfs.ntfs
/usr/share/man/man8/mkfs.ntfs.8.gz
```

When you do ls -l to mkfs.ntfs

```
      ls -l /sbin/mkfs.ntfs
      lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 25 23:53 /sbin/mkfs.ntfs -> /usr/sbin/mkntfs
                                                 (Red)                (RED)
```

See the link has been broken and there is no **mkntfs** and if you do

```
  locate mkntfs
```

Its in /sbin not in /usr/sbin

```
 /sbin/mkntfs
 /usr/share/man/man8/mkntfs.8.gz
```

So now its up to you want to want to do, remove the link and make new one OR relink the old one with another link